# What is the income limit for a qualifying relative dependent?

Tags: taxes, dependents

My younger sister is 28 years old. She lives in my house and I pay for more than 50% of her expenses (food, clothing... everything). Her income in  2018 was $7,000 for the year. She is a waitress.

Can I indicate her as my dependent or not?

Comment: Tax questions require a country tag. Are you in the U.S.?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. She would fail the gross income test, which is limited at $4,150. If she earns that amount or more, she cannot be claimed as a dependent given your relationship.

[The IRS provides a tool to help you decide](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/whom-may-i-claim-as-a-dependent) if you can claim somebody as a dependent. You should use that tool to plug in specific information to verify that you cannot claim her as a dependent.

Comment: Thanks that's what i thought just wasnt sure

Comment: i was going to accept this answer. but there is no accept button

Comment: I think you have to wait 24 hours to accept if you are a new contributor.

Comment: @john if you are the one who asked the question, it looks like you asked using a different account than the one you are using to comment, which is why there is no accept button.

Comment: i see i posted question without logging in to stackoverflow. it let me post it for some reason then i logged